# AttributeError: 'DlpServiceClient' object has no attribute 'project_path'

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dlp

I tried to use gcp code for dlp:

The code is easily found from this gcp official website documentation(no changes made other than inputting my own credentials):

```
def deidentify_with_mask(
    project, input_str, info_types, replacement_str="REPLACEMENT_STR",
):
    """Uses the Data Loss Prevention API to deidentify sensitive data in a
    string by replacing matched input values with a value you specify.
    Args:
        project: The Google Cloud project id to use as a parent resource.
        input_str: The string to deidentify (will be treated as text).
        info_types: A list of strings representing info types to look for.
        replacement_str: The string to replace all values that match given
            info types.
    Returns:
        None; the response from the API is printed to the terminal.
    """
    import google.cloud.dlp

    # Instantiate a client
    dlp = google.cloud.dlp_v2.DlpServiceClient(credentials=credentials)

    # Convert the project id into a full resource id.
    parent = f"projects/{project}"

    # Construct inspect configuration dictionary
    inspect_config = {"info_types": [{"name": info_type} for info_type in info_types]}

    # Construct deidentify configuration dictionary
    deidentify_config = {
        "info_type_transformations": {
            "transformations": [
                {
                    "primitive_transformation": {
                        "replace_config": {
                            "new_value": {"string_value": replacement_str}
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }

    # Construct item
    item = {"value": input_str}

    # Call the API
    response = dlp.deidentify_content(
        request={
            "parent": parent,
            "deidentify_config": deidentify_config,
            "inspect_config": inspect_config,
            "item": item,
        }
    )

    # Print out the results.
    print(response.item.value)
```

I received an error stating:

```
[2020-09-10 00:18:25,312] {{base_task_runner.py:101}} INFO - Job 3: Subtask task   File "pandas/_libs/lib.pyx", line 2228, in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer
[2020-09-10 00:18:25,312] {{base_task_runner.py:101}} INFO - Job 3: Subtask task   File "/usr/local/airflow/src/task/src_task.py", line 133, in <lambda>
[2020-09-10 00:18:25,312] {{base_task_runner.py:101}} INFO - Job 3: Subtask task     info_types=info_types))
[2020-09-10 00:18:25,312] {{base_task_runner.py:101}} INFO - Job 3: Subtask task   File "/usr/local/airflow/src/task/src_task.py", line 89, in deidentify_with_mask
[2020-09-10 00:18:25,312] {{base_task_runner.py:101}} INFO - Job 3: Subtask task     parent = dlp.project_path(project)
[2020-09-10 00:18:25,312] {{base_task_runner.py:101}} INFO - Job 3: Subtask task AttributeError: 'DlpServiceClient' object has no attribute 'project_path'
[2020-09-10 00:18:26,263] {{logging_mixin.py:95}} INFO - [2020-09-10 00:18:26,261] {{jobs.py:2627}} INFO - Task exited with return code 1
```

I dont understand why I received this error because when I try it locally it worked but not in airflow.

Comment: Have anyone experienced this before?

Comment: Can anyone please assist me with this please.

Answer (score 0):

This question has been fixed!

The problem is due to the version not compatible.

```
pip install google-cloud-dlp==1.0.0
```

The above code solved my problem.